# Getting error after adding web worker with cli command in Angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular, web-worker, angular8

Angular 8 has added a better support for web workers. I had no luck to get it working. Does someone know what am i doing wrong?

[Here is official guide](https://angular.io/guide/web-worker) i followed.

With this cli command i generated web worker:

```
ng generate webWorker my-worker
```

cli has generated my-worker.worker.ts file and tsconfig.worker.json file,  and updated following files: angular.json, tsconfig.app.json.

After this im getting following error:

```
ERROR in node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts(25,1): error TS6200: Definitions of the following identifiers conflict with those in another file: EventListenerOrEventListenerObject, BlobPart, HeadersInit, BodyInit, RequestInfo, DOMHighResTimeStamp, CanvasImageSource, MessageEventSource, ImageBitmapSource, TimerHandler, PerformanceEntryList, VibratePattern, AlgorithmIdentifier, HashAlgorithmIdentifier, BigInteger, NamedCurve, GLenum, GLboolean, GLbitfield, GLint, GLsizei, GLintptr, GLsizeiptr, GLuint, GLfloat, GLclampf, TexImageSource, Float32List, Int32List, BufferSource, DOMTimeStamp, FormDataEntryValue, IDBValidKey, Transferable, BinaryType, ClientTypes, EndingType, IDBCursorDirection, IDBRequestReadyState, IDBTransactionMode, KeyFormat, KeyType, KeyUsage, NotificationDirection, NotificationPermission, PushEncryptionKeyName, PushPermissionState, ReferrerPolicy, RequestCache, RequestCredentials, RequestDestination, RequestMode, RequestRedirect, ResponseType, ServiceWorkerState, ServiceWorkerUpdateViaCache, VisibilityState, WebGLPowerPreference, WorkerType, XMLHttpRequestResponseType
node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts(3473,5): error TS2687: All declarations of 'privateKey' must have identical modifiers.
node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts(3474,5): error TS2687: All declarations of 'publicKey' must have identical modifiers.
node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.webworker.d.ts(25,1): error TS6200: Definitions of the following identifiers conflict with those in another file: EventListenerOrEventListenerObject, BlobPart, HeadersInit, BodyInit, RequestInfo, DOMHighResTimeStamp, CanvasImageSource, MessageEventSource, ImageBitmapSource, TimerHandler, PerformanceEntryList, VibratePattern, AlgorithmIdentifier, HashAlgorithmIdentifier, BigInteger, NamedCurve, GLenum, GLboolean, GLbitfield, GLint, GLsizei, GLintptr, GLsizeiptr, GLuint, GLfloat, GLclampf, TexImageSource, Float32List, Int32List, BufferSource, DOMTimeStamp, FormDataEntryValue, IDBValidKey, Transferable, BinaryType, ClientTypes, EndingType, IDBCursorDirection, IDBRequestReadyState, IDBTransactionMode, KeyFormat, KeyType, KeyUsage, NotificationDirection, NotificationPermission, PushEncryptionKeyName, PushPermissionState, ReferrerPolicy, RequestCache, RequestCredentials, RequestDestination, RequestMode, RequestRedirect, ResponseType, ServiceWorkerState, ServiceWorkerUpdateViaCache, VisibilityState, WebGLPowerPreference, WorkerType, XMLHttpRequestResponseType
node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.webworker.d.ts(85,5): error TS2687: All declarations of 'privateKey' must have identical modifiers.
node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.webworker.d.ts(86,5): error TS2687: All declarations of 'publicKey' must have identical modifiers.
node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.webworker.d.ts(1074,5): error TS2375: Duplicate number index signature.
node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.webworker.d.ts(1360,5): error TS2375: Duplicate number index signature.
node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.webworker.d.ts(1434,13): error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'FormData' must be of type '{ new (form?: HTMLFormElement): FormData; prototype: FormData; }', but here has type '{ new (): FormData; prototype: FormData; }'.
node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.webworker.d.ts(2170,13): error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'Notification' must be of type '{ new (title: string, options?: NotificationOptions): Notification; prototype: Notification; readonly maxActions: number; readonly permission: NotificationPermission; requestPermission(deprecatedCallback?: NotificationPermissionCallback): Promise<...>; }', but here has type '{ new (title: string, options?: NotificationOptions): Notification; prototype: Notification; readonly maxActions: number; readonly permission: NotificationPermission; }'.
node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.webworker.d.ts(4322,13): error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'onmessage' must be of type '(this: Window, ev: MessageEvent) => any', but here has type '(this: DedicatedWorkerGlobalScope, ev: MessageEvent) => any'.
node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.webworker.d.ts(4332,13): error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'location' must be of type 'Location', but here has type 'WorkerLocation'.
node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.webworker.d.ts(4333,13): error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'onerror' must be of type 'OnErrorEventHandlerNonNull', but here has type '(this: DedicatedWorkerGlobalScope, ev: ErrorEvent) => any'.
node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.webworker.d.ts(4335,13): error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'self' must be of type 'Window', but here has type 'WorkerGlobalScope'.
node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.webworker.d.ts(4344,13): error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'navigator' must be of type 'Navigator', but here has type 'WorkerNavigator'.
```

Here is my package.json file:

```
    {
  "name": "app-name",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/fire": "^5.1.3",
    "@angular/forms": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^8.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "firebase": "^5.11.1",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "material-design-icons": "^3.0.1",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.2",
    "save": "^2.3.3",
    "smoothscroll-polyfill": "^0.4.3",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "web-animations-js": "github:angular/web-animations-js#release_pr208",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.800.1",
    "@angular/cli": "^8.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^8.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.6",
    "@types/node": "~12.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.3.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "^4.0.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.4",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.1",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.1",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "^3.4.5"
  }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: I didn't get this error. The worker run fine.

Comment: What typescript version do you use?

Comment: "typescript": "~3.4.3" and node at v10.16.0.

Comment: Tried with a fresh project and it did work, but with my main project it just doesn't work. Also created a new project and copied src folder, still doesnt work. Don't know where to look (

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had this issue too, and noticed that in a new Angular 8 project, all `tsconfig.*.json` files are in the root directory, and there is only the root `tslint.json` file.

Here's what I did:

- Copied `tslint.json`, `tsconfig.app.json`, and `tsconfig.spec.json` from a newly generated CLI 8 project to my project root.
- Deleted `tslint.json`, `tsconfig.app.json`, and `tsconfig.spec.json` from the `src` directory.
- Edited `tsConfig` values in `angular.json` to look for tsconfig files in project root, instead of in `src` directory.

If you made any modifications to the tsconfig files generated by the CLI, it might be easier to move them from `src` to the root, and edit the paths in them. I didn't change the generated files, so I just copied from a new project.

I have no idea what it is about generating a Web Worker and the addition of the `tsconfig.worker.json` that throws a wrench in an upgraded Angular project. Upgrading from 7 worked fine until I added a worker.

Comment: Right, forgot to mention that I ran the `ng generate webWorker` command after these steps. If you've already run the generate worker command, you'll need to add `"src/**/*.worker.ts"` to the `exclude` array in `tsconfig.app.json`.

Comment: I followed this instruction and it almost worked. What I had to do was add `"webWorkerTsConfig": "tsconfig.worker.json"`  to the `architect.build.options`. Note that the value `tsconfig.worker.json` also must be added to `architect.lint.options.tsConfig` too (it shows up twice in `angular.json`).

Answer (score 2):

I had this same problem. Solved it with the solution from: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/14737

Answer (score 0):

If you're using SSR (Server side rendering) don't forget to also exclude *.worker.ts`in`tsconfig.server.json`:

```
  "exclude": ["test.ts", "**/*.spec.ts", "**/*.worker.ts"],
```

Answer (score 0):

I was **missing** probably  from migrations

`"exclude": ["**/*.worker.ts"]`

into `tsconfig.app.json` file

Leading me to the following error

```
Error: C:\<...>.worker.ts is missing from the TypeScript compilation. Please make sure it is in your tsconfig via the 'files' or 'include' property.   
Error: error TS18003: No inputs were found in config file 


C:/<...>/src/tsconfig.worker.json'. Specified 'include' paths were '["src/**/*.worker.ts"]' and 'exclude' paths were '["../out-tsc/worker"]'.
```